# How to insert a php variable into a database table with input?

Tags: php, variables, input, pdo, insert

I can't figure out why my code isn't working. I'm trying to insert a dynamic variable to a table in my database with regular input in a form.

Like this, here is my query code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            // Check if movie allready is added.
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM watchlist WHERE movie_title='{$_POST['$title']}'");
            $stmt->bindParam(':movie_title', $_POST[$movie->title]);
            $stmt->execute();

            $rows = $stmt->fetchALL();
            $n = count($rows);

            if($n > 0){
            echo 'Du är redan peppad på filmen!';
            }


            $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO watchlist(movie_title, movie_des, movie_link) 
                                 VALUES ('{$_POST['title']}', '{$_POST['description']}', '{$_POST['link']}'"); 
            $sql->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
            $sql->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);
            $sql->bindParam(':link', $_POST['link']);
            $sql->execute();
            header("Location: ../index.php");
            exit;
        }
```

And here is my form:

```
$title = $movie->title;
    $description = $movie->description;
    $link = $movie->link;
    echo '<div class="view">';
    echo '<h3>' . $title . '</h3>';
    echo  $description . '<br/>';
    echo '<a href="'. $link . '" target="_blank">L&auml;s mer...</a><br/><br/>';
    echo '<a href="index.php">Tillbaka</a>';
    echo '<div class="form_dis"></div>';
    echo '<div class="form_content">';
    echo '<form action="queries/insert.php" method="post">',
         '<input type="hidden" name="title" value="$title">',
         '<input type="hidden" name="description" value="$description">',
         '<input type="hidden" name="link" value="$link">',
         '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Peppa!">',
         '</form></div>';
```

I get send back to my index page but nothing has been added to the database and I just can't figure out why. Is there anything wrong with my code that I'm missing?

Comment: Use this answer to get the PDO error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999850/pdo-error-message

Comment: Your binds don't match your column names. I.e.: `':title'` should be `':movie_title'` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've tried that but still doesn't work. And @Hast I tried using the code `print_r($sql->errorInfo())` after my execute and took the header away, and got no error message, and I got the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` in my dbconnection.

Comment: Also try changing `'{$_POST['title']}'` to `'{$_POST[title]}'` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried changing it but still no luck. Error message is working now at least so I'll try to debug it.

Comment: In addition, try 
`$stmt->execute(array(':movie_title' => $_POST['title'],':movie_des' => $_POST['description'],':movie_link' => $_POST['link']));`
instead of `$sql->execute();`

Comment: and change to `VALUES (:movie_title, :movie_des, :movie_link)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried it and it only says `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )` and I'm clueless, I'll try googling it.

Comment: See my new comment above

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still the same error after changing the values.

Comment: I'll post an answer, it'll be easier that way. Give me a few minutes. Is it just the INSERT that's giving you a hard time?

Comment: I made a mistake earlier about `$stmt->execute(array...` that should have been `$sql->execute(array...` by the way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you, Yes I believe it's only the insert, I seem to always get the error `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )`, and my database is still empty. Yeah I noticed that before and have changed it to $sql but still the same problem.

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below, it's based on what I use myself.

Comment: I edited my answer. I changed `$sql = $dbh->prepare($sql);` to `$sql = $dbh->prepare($sql_1);` Reload in case you seen it. And `$sql = "INSERT...` to `$sql_1 = "INSERT...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO watchlist (movie_title,
    movie_des,
    movie_link
    ) VALUES (
    :movie_title, 
    :movie_des, 
    :movie_link)";

    $sql = $dbh->prepare($sql_1);

    $sql->bindParam(':movie_title', $_POST['title']);
    $sql->bindParam(':movie_des', $_POST['description']);
    $sql->bindParam(':movie_link', $_POST['link']);
    $sql->execute(array(':movie_title' => $_POST['title'],':movie_des' => $_POST['description'],':movie_link' => $_POST['link']));

    if($sql != false) {
    echo "Success!";
    } else {
        echo "An error occured saving your data!";
    }

//  header("Location: ../index.php");
//  exit;
}
```

Comment: This works, but the weird thing is that it inserts the actual variables in my database, and not the data the variable referring to. So instead of for example inserting "Batman the movie" to my database it's inserting $title. Guess this has nothing to do with the code I posted. It must be something else wrong with my application, bughunting it is...

Comment: Hm... I think it may have something to do with your hidden values `<input type="hidden" name="title" value="$title">` etc. @Bondenn

Comment: Can you try changing `$sql->bindParam(':movie_title', $_POST['title']);` to `$sql->bindParam(':movie_title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);` to see if it makes it kick in? @Bondenn and try removing the `value="$title"` also

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know!

Comment: Ok, let's cross our fingers ;-) @Bondenn

Comment: Hmm now I don't get the variables in the table, and the id is always 0, so before a row looked like this: 0, $title, $description, $link, and now it's just the "0".

Comment: Woho I fixed it! By changing the `value="$title"` to `value="'.$title.'"` :)

Comment: Can you try `$sql->bindParam(':movie_title', '{$_POST['title']}';` with the braces etc. @Bondenn

Comment: But I still get id "0". I guess I have to pass another hidden input with id in the form?

Comment: Heyyyyy right on!! Glad to hear it :) @Bondenn and yes probably.

Comment: You're very much welcome, was glad to help. It's always a good feeling when a solution has been found, cheers! @Bondenn