# PDO inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new with PDO and I have little problem. Code is not inserting any data in my database, don't know why. Something wrong with binding or sth else?

```
<form action="" method= "POST">
    First name: <input type="text" name="data_name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="data_mail"><br>
    City: <input type="text" name="data_city"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tabelaDB';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'pass';

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    $name = $_POST['data_name'];
    $mail = $_POST['data_mail'];
    $city = $_POST['data_city'];

    $sql = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO data ( data_name, data_mail, data_city ) VALUES ( :data_name, :data_mail, :data_city )");

    $sql->bindValue(':data_name', $name);
    $sql->bindValue(':data_mail', $mail);
    $sql->bindValue(':data_city', $city);

    $sql->execute();
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Read this to check error http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: I think data might be a reserved word - try encapsulating in backticks - "insert into `data` ..."

Comment: @RamRaider yes but there is no **(R)** on `data` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @Saty - not seen that table before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surrond your PHP code with try - catch block as here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php then you get all information about your error.

Eidt: Here: [PDO error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999850/pdo-error-message) is similar problem and another soultion.

Comment: Ok when i add try - catch to my code, It started to work and save data into database O.o So thank you

Comment: Bit weird but I am glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should put the PHP block in a **IF** statement to check if the form is submited or a user just opens the page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tabelaDB';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'pass';

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$name = $_POST['data_name'];
$mail = $_POST['data_mail'];
$city = $_POST['data_city'];

$sql = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO data ( data_name, data_mail, data_city ) VALUES ( :data_name, :data_mail, :data_city )");

$sql->bindValue(':data_name', $name);
$sql->bindValue(':data_mail', $mail);
$sql->bindValue(':data_city', $city);

$sql->execute();
}
?>
```

To check for errors add before **prepare** :

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
```

Then add

```
print_r($db->errorInfo());
```

Comment: It started to work when I add try-catch. But when I add also your code It stopped wroking :D

Comment: cool :)) didn`t expect that