# PHP PDO updating table

Tags: php, oop, pdo

so I was following a Udemy course and then the instructor made this function

```
public function update($table, $user_id, $fields = array()){

  $columns = '';
  $i       = 1;

  foreach($fields as $name => $value){

    $columns .= "'{$name}' = :{$name}";
    if($i < count($fields)){
        $columns .= ', ';
    }
    $i++;
  }

  $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$columns} WHERE 'user_id' = {$user_id}";
  if($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)){
    foreach($fields as $key => $value){
        $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
  }

}
```

And I wrote it literally so many times after him and it just never seemed to work, would someone explain for me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: By doesn't work you mean what exactly?

Comment: It just never updates anything.

Comment: Why are you YELLING at us?

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999871/2595450) and update your question with the error

Comment: `'` != `\``:    the `'` should be backticks

Comment: Wow, it was actually the ' ` ' , thanks mate @Jeff

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$columns} WHERE 'user_id' = {$user_id}";
```

the `'` around the table name should be backticks, not single quotes:

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$columns} WHERE `user_id` = {$user_id}";
```

same here:

```
$columns .= "`{$name}` = :{$name}";
```

Comment: next time get the error messages as @Mehdi Bounya pointed out!

Comment: sure, would you tell me what do you think of this function tho? is it the best way to do it? or is there's something better I can do?

Comment: it will fail if you don't pass a filled fields-array. You need to check that first. Also check for errors and return true or false, or the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace single quotes with backticks:

```
$columns .= "`{$name}` = :{$name}";
```

and

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$columns} WHERE `user_id` = {$user_id}";
```

Just a **suggestion**: You could use an array to build the columns clause and you could directly `execute` without any `bindValue`, by just passing the `$fields` array:

```
function update($table, $user_id, $fields = array()) {

    $columns = [];

    foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
        $columns[] = "`{$name}` = :{$name}";
    }

    $sql = sprintf('UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE `user_id` = %s'
            , $table
            , implode(', ', $columns)
            , $user_id
    );

    if ($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->execute($fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I was honestly confused, I didn't really know when to use this bindParma() and bindValue() functions and when do i just bind it in the execute function

Comment: @A.Maher You are welcome. Better look into [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077108/7941334) to discover the difference btw. `bindParam` and `bindValue` once and for all ;-)

Comment: @A.Maher And apply the error handling as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32648423/7941334). Good luck.