# Not able to debug the syntax error with my SQL query

Tags: php, sql

My program isn't working and I'm unsure which point exactly I've gone wrong

- Basically, I get an artist_id from my first PHP page via get.
- I have 2 other tables. 1 Table contains the information I want. However, I need to compare my initial value, with an external table to establish a relationship from the main table where I need the information from.
- The logic behind my SQL Query is correct. However, I am unsure whether I made a syntax error which I'm not able to figure out.

Also, I find it very tedious trying to debug these programs. What would be the best way to check whether the syntax for my SQL queries are correct or not?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
table,th,td{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    <title>My second PHP page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      include 'config.php';
    ?>
    <?php
     $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=${config['dbname']};host=${config['host']};charset=utf8",
                     $config['name'], $config['pass']);
    $my_id= $_GET['val'];
    $sql = ' SELECT name, venue, schedule FROM events'
           .' WHERE event_id IN'
           .' (SELECT event_id FROM performs'
           .' WHERE artist_id = :variable) '
            .' ORDER BY schedule DESC,
                       event_id ASC';

       $stmt->execute([':variable' => $my_id ]);

  $result = $pdo->query($sql);

       echo "<table>";
      echo "<tr><th>Event name</th><th>Venue</th><th>Schedule</th></tr>";
      foreach ($result as $row) {
         echo "<tr>";
         $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
         $venue = htmlspecialchars($row['venue']);
         $schedule = htmlspecialchars($row['schedule'];
         echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
         echo"<td>".$venue."</td>";
         echo"<td>".$schedule."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";

      }

        echo "</table>";


    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: `WHERE event_id IN ( sub-query )`, i.e. missing parentheses.

Comment: you forgot () brackets for WHERE IN()

Comment: @jarlh Thanks! Stupid of me to miss that. It still doesn't seem to work after though

Comment: `'events'.'WHERE'` will result in `eventsWHERE`, which is probably not what you want. You have to insert a space either at the end of one line or at the start of the next. Ditto for couple of other lines (`INSELECT`, `performsWHERE`). You do it correctly for `:variable ORDER`, though.

Comment: Updated changes mentioned in comments.

Comment: Order by is missing a comma between the two fields being used in the order. This kind of 'please check my sql' question is ideal for the sql chat room instead of a question, which is inevitably a relatively simple syntax / typo error

Comment: The best way to debug the SQL is to use a SQL Client, connect directly to the database, and run your SQL there.

Comment: To answer a bit more helpfully about "What would be the best way to check whether the syntax for my SQL queries are correct or not?": inspect the SQL itself (not just the code that builds it) to catch silly concatenation errors, and follow the advice in [PDO error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999871/240443) about how to get feedback from the DB about what's wrong with your SQL.

Comment: Made all the changes but it still doesn't seem to be working. Also, what would be the best way I go about debugging something like this? Since I'm relatively new to PHP and SQL and I'm unaware of the syntax.

Comment: @JasonMetr so, you've done`WHERE event_id IN ( (SELECT event_id FROM performs WHERE artist_id = :variable) )`?  With the missing `()`?  *(The outer "extra" `()` are to say "here's a list" and the inner `()` are to say "here's a sub-query")*. As for debugging, connect directly to your database with a SQL Client........

Comment: _“Also, what would be the best way I go about debugging something like this? Since I'm relatively new to PHP and SQL and I'm unaware of the syntax.”_ - a) familiarize yourself better with the syntax (because otherwise debug outputs and error messages will most likely still not tell you much), and b) don’t play multiple fields at once - get the basic query syntax right using a database frontend like phpMyAdmin first, and implement it in your own PHP script afterwards.

Comment: Why are you using `.` strings, PHP allows multi-line strings no problem, and they are easier to read.

Comment: I tested my query on phpMyAdmin and it seems to be working fine. Maybe there is an error in my php code.

Comment: Have you test that your database is connected or not?

Comment: @Haritsinh Gohil Yes. My other programs work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have not any Syntax errors in your code but, you are using PDO Wrongly, when i have replicated your code in my local machine, i have got below errors:

```
  Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in your_file.php on line 12

  Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on null in your_file.php on line 12
```

You cannot bind variable using `PDO::query()`, you have to use `PDO::prepare()`.

> [PDO::prepare( string $statement [, array $driver_options = array() ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) Prepares an SQL statement to be executed by the
>   PDOStatement::execute() method. The SQL statement can contain **zero or
>   more named (:name) or question mark (?) parameter markers** for which
>   **real values will be substituted when the statement is executed**. You
>   cannot use both named and question mark parameter markers within the
>   same SQL statement; pick one or the other parameter style. Use these
>   parameters to bind any user-input, do not include the user-input
>   directly in the query.

`PDO::prepare example` from php documentation:

**Example #1 Prepare an SQL statement with named parameters**

```
   /* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
   $sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
           FROM fruit
           WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
   $sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
   $red = $sth->fetchAll();
   $sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
   $yellow = $sth->fetchAll();  
?>
```

**Example #2 Prepare an SQL statement with question mark parameters**

```
<?php  

   /* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
   $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
                         FROM fruit
                         WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
   $sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
   $red = $sth->fetchAll();
   $sth->execute(array(175, 'yellow'));
   $yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

Now, Below i am showing how to use PDO::prepare for your code, i will only show where you have to change your code:

```
<?php
 $pdo = new 
PDO("mysql:dbname=${config['dbname']};host=${config['host']};charset=utf8",
                 $config['name'], $config['pass']);
$my_id= $_GET['val'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name, venue, schedule FROM events
                       WHERE event_id IN
                      (SELECT event_id FROM performs WHERE artist_id = :variable)
                       ORDER BY schedule DESC, event_id ASC');

$stmt->execute([':variable' => $my_id ]);

foreach ($stmt as $row) {

//fetch and use you result set as you want here

}
```